# What does it mean that Neo is the "sum" of all the rejections in The Matrix?

Tags: the-matrix

How did the machines "put" all of these rejections into Neo and what does this mean? Does this give Neo his abilities? What is the overall purpose of putting all these rejections into Neo?

Answer (score 1):

My thought is that each iteration that was rejected was evaluated and tweaks were made.  Thus, Neo is an attempt to balance the rejections and provide stability for the machines and humans based on what has been learned in the past.

Comment: Can you support this with any evidence from an official source, like a quote of some sort? Evidence-based answers are much preferred to personal theories.

Comment: This doesn't explain why Neo is referred to as the "integral anomaly", nor does it answer the question of what it means that Neo is the sum of all the rejections.